# partial directory listing

Tags: python, linux

Is it possible to get a partial directory listing?

In Python, I have a process that tries to get `os.listdir` of a directory containing >100,000 of files and it takes forever.  I'd like to be able, let's say, to get a listing of the first 1,000 files quickly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might be of use: http://www.olark.com/spw/2011/08/you-can-list-a-directory-with-8-million-files-but-not-with-ls/

Comment: Next time, I would suggesting adding more subdirectories into your file set (i.e. instead of `/bigdir/00001.txt` .... `/bigdir/99999.txt`  have `/bigdir/subdir0/0001.txt` .... `/bigdir/subdir9/9999.txt`). It would make things easier (and perhaps a bit faster). Having hundred of thousands entries in a single directory is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - hindsight is truly a wonderful thing ;) - doesn't really solve the OP's current problem though, and this may not be of his own doing.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that gives me a random order of the files :) (At least I can't see a pattern)

First I found [this post in the python maillist](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2007-November/001232.html). There are 3 files attached that you have to copy to your disk (`opendir.pyx, setup.py, test.py`). Next you need the python package [Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) to compile the file `opendir.pyx` from the post. I had problems installing Pyrex and found that I had to install `python-dev` via `apt-get`. Next I installed the `opendir` package from the three above downloaded files with `python setup.py install`. The file `test.py` contains examples how to use it.

Next I was interested in how much faster this solution will be than using os.listdir and I created 200000 files with the following small shellscript .

```
for((i=0; i<200000; i++))
do
    touch $i
done
```

The following script is my benchmark running in the directory where I just created the files:

```
from opendir import opendir
from timeit import Timer
import os

def list_first_fast(i):
    d=opendir(".")
    filenames=[]
    for _ in range(i):
        name = d.read()
        if not name:
            break
        filenames.append(name)
    return filenames

def list_first_slow(i):
    return os.listdir(".")[:i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Timer("list_first_fast(100)", "from __main__ import list_first_fast")
    t2 = Timer("list_first_slow(100)", "from __main__ import list_first_slow")
    print "With opendir: ", t1.repeat(5, 100)
    print "With os.list: ", t2.repeat(5, 100)
```

The output on my system is:

```
With opendir:  [0.045053958892822266, 0.04376697540283203, 0.0437769889831543, 0.04387712478637695, 0.04404592514038086]
With os.list:  [9.50291895866394, 9.567682027816772, 9.865844964981079, 13.486984968185425, 9.51977801322937]
```

As you can see I got a speedup of a factor of 200 when returning a list with 100 filenames out of the 200000, thats pretty nice :).

I hope this is the goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: +1: interesting but I'd rather have a more standard solution.